# Why does the Facebook Graph API show some permissions declined when they were all granted and the UI accurately reflects this?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-permissions

I have authorized my app for several Facebook permissions using my own user account. If I look at the UI, I can see those permissions granted.

[image: Permissions granted in FB UI]

If I pull the permissions from the API, it shows many of these same permissions as declined for my user.

[image: FB API permissions response]

That's an API call through the Graph API Explorer using my app's token. I get the same results using cURL.

Some of these permissions require approval from FB, but they have all been approved.

[image: Permissions approved for the app by FB]

It feels like I'm missing something here. Why does the API return different results than what is shown in the UI? I'm hoping to use the API to see which permissions a user has granted for my app and to ask for a new one if they haven't already granted it. If I can't get accurate results from the API, this won't work.

Comment: You were comparing different things too - the response to /permissions is user specific and based on what that specific user accepted/declined when they saw the Login dialog for your app, the screenshot from the Status & Review tab shows which permissions Facebook has approved your app to request from users who aren't admins/developers/testers of your app

Comment: @Igy The first two screenshots show the discrepancy. The third merely shows that the app is approved for all those permissions as I know users can't grant permissions that haven't been approved which could cause a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because I had the wrong Facebook user ID. I used [a web site to find my ID](http://findmyfbid.com/) which gave me the wrong ID. I found my ID in my app's database, and this returned the correct results from the API.